# 2nd Order Non-Homogeneous Initial Value Equation with real repeated roots $x''-2x'+x=e^{2t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

So, I was trying to the question

> $$x''-2x'+x=e^{2t} ,   x(0) = 0 ,  x'(0) = 1$$

I worked the roots out as +1 repeated and found the general solution to be

$x(t)= (c1)e^{t} + (c2)te^{t}$

The particular solution I tried was

$x_p = e^{at}$

$x'_p = ae^{at}$

$x''_p = (a^2)e^{at}$

I subbed these into the initial equation to get

$(a^2)e^{at} - 2ae^{at} + e^{at} = e^{2t}$

The problem is that I don't know how to carry on. I missed a lot of my college year due to being ill and I am currently trying to self teach the topic for my upcoming august exams since i missed the summer ones.

Any help would be appreciated! ( Also, this is my first post so, apologies for the formatting errors ! )

Comment: Exponentials with different half-lives/growth rates are linearly independent, so if your final equation is true for variable $t$, then $a=2$. Also, the particular solution could have a coefficient other than $1$.

Comment: For formatting, just put dollar signs around the expression. Use braces to group things (especially exponents like e^{2t}), and underscore for subscripts (like c_1). https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Milk : The form of particular solution is $ce^{2t}$. You only have to determine $c$ to satisfy the ODE.

Comment: @mr_e_man could you explain or provide some sort of material that explains how you found a? The problem with my self teaching is that I only really know the steps to do a question not the specific examples and tricks , thank you for the answer and formatting tips :)

Comment: Here http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_undeterminedcoeff.cfm you can find a table to look for particular solutions of several ODEs. As @JJacquelin said the trial function in your case must be $ce^{2t}.$

Comment: The exponential functions $e^{at}$ and $e^{2t}$ cannot be equal (or proportional) for all $t$ unless their growth rates are equal: $a=2$.

Comment: @JJacquelin so if i change to $(x_p)=ae^{2t}$ and follow the same order and then solve for a ( i got 1/3 ) , it should be okay to move onto adding the general solutions and particular solutions?

Comment: $(ae^{2t})''-2(ae^{2t})'+ae^{2t}=e^{2t} \Rightarrow (4ae^{2t})-2(2ae^{2t})+ae^{2t}=e^{2t} \Rightarrow a=1$.

Comment: @farruhota I forgot to multiply the first derivative by 2, thank you!

Comment: @mfl thank you, that table helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another method for additional purposes:
$$x''-2x'+x=e^{2t}$$
$$(e^{-t}x''-e^{-t}x')-(e^{-t}x'-e^{-t}x)=e^{t}$$
$$(e^{-t}x')'-(e^{-t}x)'=e^{t}$$
$$e^{-t}x'-e^{-t}x=e^{t}+C_1$$
$$(e^{-t}x)'=e^{t}+C_1$$
$$e^{-t}x=e^{t}+C_1t+C_2$$
$$x=e^{2t}+C_1te^{t}+C_2e^{t}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got from the first line to the second line, did you just multiply by $e^{-t}$ and then factorise the line?

Comment: Yes, It is ....

Comment: would you be able to confirm that $c_1 = -1 $ and $c_2 = 0$ ?

Comment: $x(0)=0$ gives $C_2=-1$.

Comment: Also from $e^{-t}x'-e^{-t}x=e^{t}+C_1$ we have $e^{0}x'(0)-e^{0}0=e^{0}+C_1$ then $C_1=0$.

Comment: I'm assuming the notation of $C_x$ isn't overly important as long as the answers are correct ?